# Probability Lock-Key Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations

[image]

I really doubt the solution provided by my coaching institute for this problem. I think none of the options are correct. Please guide me with the problem. It is not a homework problem. It was asked in a practice test conducted by my coaching institute.

Comment: What about the answer do you doubt?

Comment: I'd attribute this to a typo or a translation error rather than a logic error. (After all, there are other errors, for example "trial" is spelled "trail".) They are not calculating the probability that the lock will open *in the nth trial*:  they are calculating the probability that the lock will open *in n trials (or less)*. For *that* problem, the solution (c) is correct.

Comment: By the way, the probability that the lock is opened in the *nth trial* is $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$, if I am not mistaken. This is because it is *not* opened in the first $n-1$ trials and *is* opened in the nth.

Comment: My English is not good enough to decode the part: "open in $n^{th} $ trial". Help needed.

Comment: @user8734617 even I was thinking the same thing. And that didn't match any of the options. So, I left this problem in the exam.